# Bash true numerical order

Tags: bash

How can I order files in a directory by their true numeric order.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file11.txt
...
```

I think it's called : Natural Order

Comment: Would it be an option to pad the numbers with zeroes when creating the files?

Comment: What is the bash connection here?

Comment: "bash" tends to suggest that the problem is to be solved on some kind of Unix OS and not Windows.

Comment: I love it when you have to use guesswork and intuition to work out what the questioner is really trying to do!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the `-v` option:

```
ls -v file*
file1
file2
file11
file12
```

Another option may be using `sort -V`, assuming that one is available on your platform:

```
ls file* |sort -V
```

Comment: Only with GNU 'ls'; on MacOS X, the 'ls -v' option is 'Force unedited printing of non-graphic characters'.

Comment: `$ ls -v` returns `test5.txt  text1.txt  text2.txt  text11.txt` for me.

Comment: What about using sort (see edit above)? That one also comes with a natural sort option.

Comment: @icanhasserver: Which OS/Dist? On Debian Lenny, that option isn't available.

Comment: sort (GNU coreutils) 8.5
Packaged by Gentoo (8.5 (p1))

Comment: -v is sort by version on my ls: "ls version 4.4.218 2009/04 for Microsoft Windows"

Comment: the numerical order command is now "sort -n", not -V, for mac OS 10.9

Answer (score 5):

For this particular list of files, sort numerically starting at the fifth character of the first field.

```
$ ls file*|sort -k1.5n
file1
file2
file11
file12
```

Answer (score 1):

If all filenames are `fileSOMENUMBER.txt`, try this:

```
ls -1|sed 's:^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*$:\1:g'|sort -n|sed 's:^\(.*\)$:file\1.txt:g'
```