# Bash true numerical order including negative?

Tags: bash, sorting

`ls -v ./file*` sorts filenames in natural order :

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file11.txt
```

but if we include negative numbers, it give back :

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file11.txt
file-5.txt
file-18.txt
```

**How to sort in natural order including negative numbers ?**

---

Inspired by [Bash true numerical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234347/)

Comment: I think the problem is that those aren't seen as negative numbers as much as delimited numbers so they are sorted by prefix. If you know you want to consider those negative numbers and sort on them you would probably need to do the sorting yourself (with an array and a loop or with awk/perl/etc.).

Comment: The `-v` option was introduce to sort *version* numbers, which tend not be negative.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the following works:

```
$ ls file*|sort -k1.5n  #start sorting at character 5
file-18.txt
file-5.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
file11.txt
```

To test, do :

```
echo "a black"  > file-18.txt
echo "e white"  > file-5.txt
echo "i red"    > file1.txt
echo "o green"  > file2.txt
echo "u blue"   > file11.txt
echo "voyelles" > file013.47.txt
ls file*|sort -k1.5n  #start sorting at character 5
```